# How to group and merge results together in Views?

Tags: views

I have Views setup to list only nodes of a certain type and group them by a field. It looks somewhat like this:

*Group 1:

Title A

Title B*

*Group 2:

Title C*

Now I want to merge the Titles togehter so it looks like this:

*Group 1:

Title A & Title B*

*Group 2:

Title C*

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you'd like them grouped, i.e. to include the field that you are grouping them by and what data in it determines how they are grouped? You may be interested in [views_merge_rows](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_merge_rows)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in following ways,

1) Choose your views format as table under Format 'Format: Table', Then click settings. You can find a table listing your selected fields. near to each field there is an option to choose column. There choose your  Title B s column to Title A and in the separator provide '&' . Ensure Grouping field has chose. Now you will get a display in following format
Group 1:
Title A & Title B

OR

2) After grouping, Choose Exclude from display option for your Title A  field. Then for second field choose Rewrite results. There you can find Replacement patterns. Use your token in appropriate format. eg. [title] & [nid]

Hope this may helps you

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Title A and Title B are 2 diffrent nodes. If I have like 40 nodes grouped together I want them to automaticly be displayed as "Title A & Title B & Title C......". I only have 1 Title field for each node.

Answer (score 0):

I think views aggregator module may help you
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator